# Conflicting CXF jar version between a Java project and a nested project

Tags: java, eclipse, cxf, conflict, dependency-management

I have 2 java projects: capturingapp and epcis-queryclient. These are open source projects which I imported in Eclipse. capturingapp runs in Tomcat.
 
epcis-queryclient is nested in capturingapp (i.e. it is listed in the Projects tab in Java Build Path in Eclipse)
epcis-queryclient uses the `cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.9.jar` library.
capturingapp uses the `cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.1.jar` library.

I have an error at runtime: capturingapp calls a method present in epcis-queryclient which needs the `ClientOnlyHTTPTransportFactory` class (present in v2.2.9 of cxf), but it fails because it looks in v2.6.1 which does not contain that class anymore.
How could I solve this situation?
Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> These are open source projects

Great news!

> How could I solve this situation?

I will tell you the best way to solve this problem!

You can update the code of epcis-queryclient to use `cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.1.jar`, using your programming skills. I am sure they will be pleased to receive such a contribution!

**But first** check to see if they have already done it, in git master / SVN HEAD / hg tip, or in an experimental branch.